# How to tell which version of flash was used to make a swf file

Tags: flash, windows-ce

I am trying to work with a flash application in windows CE.

the folder containing the files has several .swf files in it. We'll call two of them abc1.swf and abc2.swf.

I have created two html pages which when viewed on my PC open up either file and view it just fine.

```
<html>
<body>
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="abc1.swf">
<embed src="abc1.swf" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I copy the directory to my windows CE 6.0 R3 device, the page that opens abc2.swf shows correctly. But the page that is supposed to open abc1.swf just shows a blank white area.

I am pretty sure that the abc1.swf is only supposed to redirect to abc2.swf (or put within a frame) given it's 1kb size and the fact that I can see the text abc2.swf within it when opened in notepad.

I've been told that the flash player built into Windows CE 6.0 R3 is only capable of supporting flash v8 or less. I suspect that perhaps the issue with abc.swf could be that it was built with a newer version of flash such as v9 or v10.

Is there any way for me to tell which version of flash a given .swf file requires using only freely available tools? Or, does anyone have any other theories about what would cause abc1.swf to work on my PC but not on my windows CE device?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Hex-Editor, look at the 4th byte of the SWF. It is the version number.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that was not the problem with the swf (it was version 7 which should work) but it's a great easy answer to my question.